# Pandas remove duplicates by condition (not with regular drop_duplicate)

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

(It is not as easy as just removing the duplicates with drop_duplicates. This question is not duplicated)

I have following dataframe

```
   number       doc    type    sum
0      15  document   credit   10000
1      15  doc        credit   9999
2      16  passport   debit    20000
3      16  pas        debit    19999
4      16  passport   debit    25000
```

Row is considered duplicated if number and type are equal, doc and sum are not.
So I need to remove them somehow specifying this condition

The result of removing duplicates should be

```
   number       doc    type    sum
0      15  document  credit  10000
2      16  passport   debit  20000
4      16  passport   debit  25000
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: @DYZ I think is not as simple as just removing duplicates, the other columns have to be different

Comment: Why the 4 row is in the output, if has number and type equal to first one and doc and sum different

Comment: @DaniMesejo because  doc column is the same, but HAVE to be different

Comment: @DaniMesejo it can sound stupid but same passport in doc is not a duplicate in this case

Comment: Why if you have multiple type of docs for same number and type, for example the last row is doc instead of passport (row 4). What would be the output?

Comment: in this case output will be row 0 and 2. 4 will be considered as duplicate. 

if number ant type are equal I dont care if there is an existing doc or existing sum. I am to consider it as dublicate and save first hit